# "The partner returned a bad sign-in name or password error. Fedration error" azure

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure

I am getting this error in azure log when I try to publish a console application which will create a list in SharePoint.

Also this error is coming when `context.executeQuery()` is done.
What do I need to solve this issue.

Comment: It was a access related issue, Admin access is needed on sharepoint site collection where list is created using this exe which we publish to azure

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I have recently got the same error. You can get run into this scenario, when your SharePoint policy was changed to permit only certain type of browsers. For example in my case IE was approved, while Chrome/Firefox and everything else including my .Net application, were forbidden. Easy to test, just try to open SP with other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the account I was using to connect to SharePointOnline in the code had 2FA enabled.  Using a different account with the same access but no 2FA worked perfectly.